# When is a "related:" comment actually appropriate?

Tags: discussion, related-problems

I've got a question sitting here on SuperUser that is a couple of years old, has a good number of upvotes, hasn't seen activity in quite some time, and has been answered to satisfaction.

Is it appropriate for a given user to post "Related: [link]" comments, linking questions that

- are on other SE network sites,
- are (much) newer than my question, and
- are actually *linking back* to my question here on SU, either in comments or even as an answer?

I have some previous reason to suspect the user posting these comments as trolling me, and would like to know if I'm justified in believing so, or overreacting.

Comment: I do this a lot ._. I tend to think its useful when another question is similar, and the context might be useful.

Comment: [this one?](http://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why). Looks like that user is putting related on a lot of related questions across the network. Unless I'm missing where the user is ending all paths at an answer of his, I don't see this as trolling.

Comment: @Raystafarian: The "previous reason" was a blatantly plagiarizing answer to that question where he basically re-wrote all the workarounds posted (like he did on basically all other sites)... But yeah, blood pressure is down, I mean, whatever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not being very specific, so I can give you a very unspecific answer: it's generally fine to post such a comment. Put yourself into the position of someone who has the same problem and is looking for help. They may be interested in seeing other questions which describe the same (or a similar) issue. Sometimes you might find information on another site that isn't mention here—or vice-versa.

As long as the comment is *actually* related to the question, it's fine.